# How to perform intent function in selected row of Listview

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I have created one listview of some names,what i need is when i will click selected row it will go to that page only,on click on different row it will move to the same class but different content.I think it will move by question id.could anybody help me how to pass the question id Or any other method to do this..

here is my code..

```
private OnItemClickListener mlist = new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


    }       
};
```

Comment: You mean same activity with multiple sections?

Comment: @Anukool no i mean if i will click one name it will move to another page have the description of that name..

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9647042/593709) post to pass data from ListView to next Activity. [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8352538/593709) is also good. and specially [google](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=android+passing+data+to+another+activity).

Comment: @AdilSoomro thanks ..but i need that when i will click any row it will move to that particular rowpage only..

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -

```
private OnItemClickListener mlist = new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        if(Some condition)
        {
            Intent i= new Intent(YourActivity.this,ActivityOne.class);
            // To pass data 
            i.putExtra("SomeId", someValue);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else if(Some other condition)
        {
            Intent i= new Intent(YourActivity.this,SecondActivityTwo.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something else--
        }

    }       
};
```

And in the other activity -

```
String identifier = getIntent().getExtras().getString("SomeId");
```

Comment: i want that suppose you click first row it will move to aaa.class..next if you will click third row it should move to aaa.class with different content ..by passing userid..or something

Comment: @ Sangita : you will have to explain a little more .

Comment: k..look..i have a 10 list row..on each row onclick..it will display some content..which willbe in listview also

Comment: @ Sangita : On Click are you populating a new ListView ? Or You are talking about the nested listviews?

Comment: on row onclick it will show some custom listview which will be having the content of the row only..

Answer (score -1):

Here I've given an example assuming you have user list and clicking on item you want to show user profile...

In List_Act activity...

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowitem,parent,false);

    convertView.setTag(UserId);
}

private OnItemClickListener mlist = new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Intent i=new Intent(List_Act.this, Profile_Act.class);
            int UserId = ((View)v.getParent()).getTag();
            i.putExtra("UserId", UserId);  //Setting variable you want to pass to another activity
            startActivity(i);
        }       
    };
```

in Profile_Act activity in onCreate()

```
String UserId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("UserId");  //retrieving value in another activity
```

now you'll have UserId variable set and you can use it...

Comment: @Sangita yes you'll have to assign tag to the item in getView()  of adapter class, this tag should be id of the user or something you wanna pass... and in the onclick method you can get the tag id and pass...

Comment: @Sangita now check... in the getView method I've set the tag for the list item...

Comment: i have already create base adapter ..i need to pass the name id from one activity to another

Comment: @Sangita yes in the class extended by BaseAdepter you would have overrided method public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) in this method you can set tag as I've mentioned, and in onclick you can retrieve value from the tag and using putExtra you can pass it...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24561/discussion-between-mohit-mehta-and-sangita)

Comment: sorry..i can not accept your answer is fine..but finally it is not working

Comment: @Sangita It's ok... I could have solved it if you could sent me the sample code